# Display a message is not giving result?

Tags: status-messages, mobile-tools

I like to show a message on 1 page of my website after login. Therefore I made a rule. To determine the mobile device I use module : [mobile_detect](https://www.drupal.org/project/mobile_detect).
I installed the corresponding library. Checking the status is saying it is available.

They module readme shows the example code:

```
$detect = mobile_detect_get_object();
$is_mobile = $detect->isMobile();
```

So when I rewrite this in a message with php eval like this:

```
#
<?php 
$detect = mobile_detect_get_object();
$is_mobile = $detect->isMobile();
print ($is_mobile);
?>
#
```

So the result should be : #TRUE# or #FALSE# but I get back # #.

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

> A boolean **TRUE** value is converted to the string *"1"*. Boolean **FALSE** is converted to *""* (the empty string). This allows conversion back and forth between boolean and string values.

You can use below code instead

```php
print ($is_mobile ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");
```

Comment: thxs, it worked